# How do I run an array to run through all the sprites and get an animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is a scriptablobject which has an array of sprites running, when you save the hero, loaded all the information from this scriptablobject and must play this animation, changing sprites in turn, including thus animation
How to do this, the for loop does not work
I equalize the sprite renderer.sprite to this array under the index 0, all this in the method of loading

```
public class Character : ScriptableObject 
{
    [SerializeField] private float HP; 
    [SerializeField] private float Damage;
    public CustomAnimation run; 
}
```

This entity has a load method that loads the sprite when you spawn

```
public class CharacterData : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] private Character _data; 
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer; 

    public void Load(Character data)
    {
        _data = data; 
        spriteRenderer.sprite = _data.run.sprites[0];
    }
}
```

the entities of the spawner itself

```
[SerializeField] private Transform[] spawnPoints;
[SerializeField] private Transform spawnParent; 
[SerializeField] private CharacterData prefabSource; 
[SerializeField] private CharacterList characters; 

public void Spawn() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.Count; i++) 
    { 
        CharacterData spawnedObject = Instantiate(prefabSource, spawnPoints[i].position, Quaternion.identity, spawnParent); 
        spawnedObject.Load(characters[i]); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So of I understand correctly what you get is simply a `Sprite[]` and you want to iterate through them simulating an animation

```
public class CharacterData : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] private Character _data; 
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer; 

    // adjust the target frames per second of your "animation"
    [SerializeField] private float framesPerSecond = 24f;

    public void Load(Character data)
    {
        _data = data; 
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(Animation());
    }

    private IEnumerator Animation()
    {
        // initializing in order to sure start with 0 the first time
        var time = -Time.deltaTime;

        // o.O
        // For IEnumerator this is fine as long as you yield somewhere inside
        while(true)
        {
            // increase by the time passed since last frame
            // 0 for the first iteration, see above 
            time += Time.deltaTime;

            // Step 1: calculates frame index according to configured fps
            // Step 2: wraps around index of exceeding actual frames array length 
            var index = Mathf.RountToInt(time * framesPerSecond) % _data.run.sprites.Length;

            // assign current frame
            spriteRenderer.sprite = _data.run.sprites[index];

            // "pause", let unity render this frame and continue from here in the next frame
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```